# Retrieving the wrong selected radiobutton in a multi-fragmented viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm a long time lurker trying to learn Android coding (with Android Studio). So far I have solved all my issues just by googling them. But now I am really desperate, so I hope someone can help me.

**I am trying to code a quiz**:
I use a ViewPager to create a number of fragments (here 5). The first fragment (StartView.java) is just some text display with a button to start the quiz. The following fragments all have the same layout, just different questions. So I use only one layout (QuestionView.java and fragment_view1.xml). Each fragment has 5 radio buttons, grouped in a radiogroup. In addition, a button is used to advance to the next fragment. When this button is clicked, the text of the pressed radio button is retrieved and passed back to the main activity.

**My Problem in short**:
The code runs without error (on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus) but the code does not retrieve the right selected RadioButton. The first QuestionView fragment does give me the value of the selected radiobutton. But for the next QuestionView fragments I am always getting the selected radiobutton from the previous fragment.

**A more extended description of the observed behavior**:
**(A)** I run the program and press the start quiz button (on Fragment #0, i.e. the StartView). In the following instance of the QuestionView fragment (F #1), I select a RadioButton, say number 1. When I press the 'next' Button, this number is then printed in the logcat ("Question view - TEXT 1", correct behavior).
**(B)** So I advance to the next fragment (F #2), I again select a RadioButton, say number 3. But when I press the button, the RadioButton of the previous fragment is printed in the logcat (i.e.: the logcat reads "Question view - TEXT 1", and not number 3.) **(C)** In the next fragment (F #3), after selecting a radioButton (for example number 5) and pressing the 'next' button, the number from the previous fragment (#2) is printed in the logcat ("Question view - TEXT 3", I expected number 5). So the retrieved number is always the one of the previous fragment.

I hope I described my problem adequately. Please don't hesitate to tell me when I explained it poorly - english is not my native language, and explaining even less:).

Thank you very much, I appreciate your efforts.

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements QuestionView.OnDataPass{

private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyAdapter pageAdapter;
private static final int ITEMS = 5;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.pager) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pageAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Fragment[] tabList = new Fragment[ITEMS]; 
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ITEMS;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (tabList[i] != null) {
            return tabList[i];
        } else {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    tabList[0] = StartView.newInstance("Introduction screen");
                    return  tabList[0];
                case 1:
                    tabList[1] = QuestionView.newInstance("Question 1");
                    return tabList[1];
                case 2:
                    tabList[2] = QuestionView.newInstance("Question 2");
                    return tabList[2];
                case 3:
                    tabList[3] = QuestionView.newInstance("Question 3");
                    return tabList[3];
                case 4:
                    tabList[4] = QuestionView.newInstance("Question 4");
                    return tabList[4];
            }
        }
        return null ;
    }
}

@Override
public void WorkData(String data) {
    Log.d("LOG", " Activity - TEXT   " + data);
}}
```

QuestionView.java

```
public class QuestionView extends Fragment {

    OnDataPass dataPasser;   

    private TextView firstText;
    private Button btn;
    RadioGroup rgOpinion;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public interface OnDataPass  {
        public void WorkData(String data);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1, container, false);
        firstText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneText);
        firstText.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneBtn);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rgOpinion = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(rgOpinion.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String text = selected.getText().toString();
                Log.d("LOG", " Question view - TEXT  " +text);
                dataPasser.WorkData(text);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
            }

        });
        return view;
    }

    public static QuestionView newInstance(String text) {
        QuestionView f = new QuestionView();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;
    }
}
```

fragment_view1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height= "fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hintergrundbild"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">
    </ImageView>


    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="weiter..."
        android:id="@+id/viewOneBtn"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="MY PAGE TITLE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/radBut1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/radioButtonAnimationMovies"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButtonAnimationMovies"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButtonAnimationMovies"
            android:checked="false" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/radBut2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:checked="false" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/radBut3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonAnimationMovies"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButtonAnimationMovies"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButtonAnimationMovies"
            android:checked="false" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/radBut4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonHorrorMovies"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButtonHorrorMovies"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButtonHorrorMovies"
            android:checked="false" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/radBut5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonComedyMovies"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButtonComedyMovies"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButtonComedyMovies"
            android:checked="false" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="449dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="449dp"></FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using getActivity(), which will look for the Id on the whole activity (not just current fragment)

```
rgOpinion = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(rgOpinion.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Try using the view you have defined previously on onCreateview() like this

```
rgOpinion = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(rgOpinion.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Comment: Hi Cilvet, thanks for your reply. Your comment explains a lot. So I changed my code and tried it, but I get a NullPointerException in the line `RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(rgOpinion.getCheckedRadioButtonId());`. But I sense where I am wrong.

Comment: you have to use the second code I posted! not the first one xD sorry I didnt answer earlier. If there is not a checked action button, it will probably crush since you are asking for one, so you have to check first